# Making hardware peripherals for Windows work with Linux too

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

I found this really nice external wireless keyboard and mouse combo for my laptop, and was about to buy it when I just noticed that the OSs supported include only the various versions of Windows. Can I do some thing (on my own or otherwise) to make it run on Linux (I am not much of a geek)? I use Ubuntu and Windows 7 (dual boot), and having an external keyboard/mouse which just runs on one OS would be quite useless.

(In case anyone is interested in having a look at the actual product, [here it is](http://www.logitech.com/en-za/keyboards/keyboard-mice-combos/8411) on the Logitech website! )

ps: Confused with the question title and tags...edits are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the maker may not support the use of the product with Linux, [it might work without problems](http://wenlong.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/using-logitech-k400-wireless-keyboard-with-linux/) - However it would be wise to find out first or at least inform the seller that you intend to use it with Ubuntu Linux and expect to return for a refund if it doesn't work with Linux.

---

Update.

To make peripherals work with an operating system, you need "drivers", small pieces of software that enable the operating system to communicate with the peripheral and make use of it. Drivers come from several sources

- Peripheral vendor (for each O/S they support)
- O/S vendor (for each peripheral they support)
- Chipset vendor (for peripherals incorporating their chipset)
- Third parties.

It is worth checking with the operating system provider
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsKeyboard

---

If in doubt, choose a [different product?](http://www.logitech.com/en-hk/keyboards/keyboard-mice-combos/7313)

> System Requirements
>
> Windows® XP, Windows Vista®, Windows® 7 or **Linux® kernel 2.6 or later**
>   USB port

Comment: Well your link gives me good hope, but can I trust a random blog?? Any...ahem... 'reputation' of this person/blog ?

Comment: @pnp: You can't completely trust a random blog - which is why you should agree with the seller that you'll return the product if it doesn't work. But see updated answer too.

Comment: Based on your answer, your references and these links I found- (http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.in/2012/04/logitech-mk220-wireless-combo.html), (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1375326), let this discussion rest in peace now!

Comment: The keyboard / mouse don't require drvers. I just bought the same and it works fine without doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience with Logitech Wireless Combo MK220 product, it is running without problems right after plugging into USB on Raspberry Pi with XBMC installed - running Raspbian Linux. I also took the risk of purchasing the product without reliably knowing, that it works under Linux. In my case, it is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful I am afraid - even Logitech explicitly states it is not supported: http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/26640/~/supported-operating-systems-for-the-mk220

**EDIT** as per slhck suggestion in comments:

From Logitech site:

> The MK220 is supported by:
>
> Windows 7
>   Windows XP
>   Windows Vista
>
> NOTE: The MK220 isn't supported on Windows 98, Windows ME, Windows
>   2000, UNIX, Linux or Macintosh operating systems.

Comment: Instead of just answering with a link, could you please include the most relevant parts here, on-site? Thanks!

Comment: I _know_ that Dave (maybe I should have had mentioned these myself), and that is precisely the reason I am asking this question!

Comment: I asked the guy in the shop he said the should all work. Just plugged in the mouse and it does.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought the same kit. There is a usb dongle that plugs into the computer. No drivers, and it seems to be working without any effort on my part.

My assumption is that the wirelss communication happens independently of the computer, and the signals that the dongle sends will be the same as a standard keyboard.